# Laravel - Call to a member function save() on string

Tags: arrays, json, laravel-5, save

I am unable to save an array of items from session to mysql database with an error:

`"Symfony \ Component \ Debug \ Exception \ FatalThrowableError (E_ERROR)
  Call to a member function save() on string"`

When I do a dd(Dump and Die) the array is displayed as below:

```
    "{"1":{"name":"Bajiya","quantity":4,"price":"34.00"},
    "2":{"name":"Gulha","quantity":2,"price":"3.00"},
    "3":{"name":"kavaabu","quantity":1,"price":"2.00"}}"
```

Below is the controller store function:

```
public function storeCart(Request $request){

    $cart = new Cart;
    $cart= session()->get('cart');
    $cart =  json_encode($cart);
    $cart->save();
}
```

I have a table in my Database with columns for id and cart. I want the array above to be saved in the cart column.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Works with the function below.

```
public function storeCart(Request $request){

    $cart = new Cart();
    $cart->cart = $request->session()->get('cart');
    $cart->save();
    $request->session()->forget('cart');
    return redirect()->route('/');
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Each time you override previous variable `$cart`

```
$cart = new Cart; //put into $cart instance of Cart class
$cart = session()->get('cart'); // overwrite other data to variable $cart
$cart = json_encode($cart); // json_encode converts object/array to json (so at this moment you overwrite string to variable `$cart`
$cart->save(); //you're trying to call function on json)))
```

Please try to understand, what exactly you want to do))

Answer (score 1):

To put my explanation in a simple term, you need to point to the columns in the DB where the records will be persisted. The code could look like this below

```
$cart = new Cart;
$cart->name= session()->get('name');
$cart->quantity =  session()->get('quantity');
$cart->price =  session()->get('price');
$cart->save();
```

Since you are saving an array of items you may want to use the foreach and the code will change to something like this:

```
foreach ($cart as $item){
  $item->name= session()->get('name');
  $item->quantity =  session()->get('quantity');
  $item->price =  session()->get('price');
  $item->save();
}
```

You may also want to consider using relationships. Hope this makes sense and helps.